# Excel vlookup help

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

```
=IF(N101<>"",ROUND(VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$39,12,FALSE)/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0)
```

That is the current VLOOKUP in the spreadsheet that is returning the wrong data. I didn't write it, it was on a spreadsheet before I came to the company.

What I want to happen is look up the value in $N101 then I want it to find the row that is the same from i30 to i40 take whats in ((k30-j30/)/(1-(U$96+U$98)) when I say k30 I actually mean k30-k40 depending on the match.

Comment: it is not clear from your description. Is the value in N101 findable in column I? if so, can't the lookup range only be I30:K40, then return column 3? Perhaps a sample would help us visualize what you have.  Or maybe using the INDEX function is more suitable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(N101<>"",ROUND((VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$40,3,FALSE)-
                    VLOOKUP($N101,$I$30:$U$40,4,FALSE))/(1-(U$96+U$98)),0),0)
```

Comment: this was the solution for you?

Comment: @datatoo, it wasn't my question, I was just the editor.  bugz will have to decide if it was the solution.

Comment: @bugz was Lance Roberts solution correct for you? The formula appears correct

Comment: sorry I looked at you having edited the question rather than the original submit.